# DataType attribute wrecking jQuery datepicker on Datetime field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, jquery-ui-datepicker, editorfor

I am using *MVC 4* and *Razor views* and am having trouble understanding why the Edit view on my Date field is not binding properly to the built in jQuery datepicker.

The field is of datatype `Date` in the Database, and `DateTime` in the domain model.  I do not wish to show time, only the date. The field is required and needs formatting.

My view looks like this :

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Appointment.EndDate)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Appointment.EndDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Appointment.EndDate)
</div>
```

If my metadata on this field is

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "End Date must be a valid date, like 05/13/2016.")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "End Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public object EndDate { get; set; }
```

then my editor output on edit.cshtml is this:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field End Date must be a date." data-val-required="End Date must be a valid date, like 05/13/2016." id="Appointment_EndDate" name="Appointment.EndDate" type="date" value="05/09/2013">
```

this draws a jQuery datepicker BUT WITHOUT SETTING THE VALUE.

If I remove the DataType attribute from my metadata and leave everything else the same:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "End Date must be a valid date, like 05/13/2016.")]
[Display(Name = "End Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public object EndDate { get; set; }
```

then my editor output is this:

```
<input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field End Date must be a date." data-val-required="End Date must be a valid date, like 05/13/2016." id="Appointment_EndDate" name="Appointment.EndDate" **type="datetime"** value="05/09/2013">
```

this draws a plain text box (no datepicker) with the value properly set.

I would like to use the datepicker but set the correct value, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

(i used a nullable datetime; but it isnt really needed)

and in the GUI use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndDate )
```

this should work.