# ASP.Net MVC date validation always saying "field must be a number" (???)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, jquery-ui-datepicker, razor-pages

I have a very simple model with a field declared as follows:

```cs
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

The field has no custom validation, or any attributes besides Display.

Now, I generate an editor for this field in a Razor page with

```
@Html.FieldLabelAndEditorFor(m => m.BirthDate)
```

When I try to post the form in which the control is contained, if I enter any value (valid or not), I invariably get a message saying

> The field "Birthdate" must be a number.

and obviously the form doesn't post.

The only remarkable thing I can think of is that the OS in my PC is in Spanish, which changes the date format to "yyyy/MM/dd", but nothing special other than that. Not that I can see how that could have anything to do with it though.

Any ideas what can be going on here?
Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the generated HTML code.

```
<input class="text-box single-line hasDatepicker input-validation-error" 
data-val="true" data-val-number="El campo 'BirthDate' debe ser un número." 
data-val-required="El campo BirthDate es obligatorio." et="true" 
id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="text" value="27/09/2019" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="BirthDate-error" 
aria-label="Use the arrow keys to pick a date" aria-invalid="true">
```

Comment: Try adding `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` to the BirthDate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, no luck. That changed the editing control generated, but the validation still works the same.

Comment: In case it's of any help, I added the HTML code to the OP.

Comment: Well, that looks like jquery ui datepicker. Here is a link with some attributes you can add to control the formatting and error message. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324735/datatype-attribute-wrecking-jquery-datepicker-on-datetime-field

Comment: Are you able to debug and tell us what value is being returned to the controller?

Comment: AFAICT I'm never reaching the controller. The validation appears to be client side, and it cancels the call to the controller action.

Comment: I don't think FieldLabelAndEditorFor is from ASP.NET MVC. Did you create it or is it from a third party library?

Comment: You're right. Sorry that I didn't explain. That function just creates a label and calls Html.EditorFor for the field. I tried using EditorFor directly and the issue remains.